# Add id to headers on information pages so they can be targetted in links using #

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

On information pages such as the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page, headers should have an id, so that reviewers can easily target them in links. For example, if an answer is posted with only a link as content, we should be able to link them to stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer#link-context.

As a side note: it would also be nice if the system could detect if a post only contains a link, and either prevent the answer from being posted, or show a warning message.

Comment: Don't you mean `name`s not ids?

Comment: @Ben Brocka: IDs can be used with hash fragments in lieu of named anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike our [ever-growing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+to+faq) [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), I don't think the content in any of the How to Ask/Answer sections — or even the entire pages for that matter — is long enough to warrant adding anchors. A *little* scrolling wouldn't hurt now and then (my browser window is resized to 1280×800).

Comment: I browse on a 9" monitor, you insensitive clod! :p